# How "turn on data" works

Tags: internet

Instead of letting all the apps connect to internet, is it possible to let selected apps connect to internet?

Hence my question how "turn on data" works?

Comment: Have you tried using "NoRoot Firewall" APK from Google Play?

Comment: (I did a long ago)Firewall drop/reject app basis requests. means app is constanly sending request which causes performance strain.

Comment: Without modifying the app, I don't think there's a way to stop them from trying to send a request anyway.

Comment: Thats why trying to know how "turn on data" worKs. Perhaps, can get insight!